# Data passing between two View Controller Swift IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have been making simple GPA calculation app. and it takes user input from lot of text fields and do the calculate and show the result.i want to show that result in `2ndViewController`

```
@IBAction func CalculateGpa(sender: AnyObject){
//all the calculation happen here
//example
        let gpa:Float = TotalGiCi/TotalGi

}
```

and i want to pass that `gpa` to my `2ndViewController` label. 
so i did the coding like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var ResultViewController : ViewControllerResult = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerResult

        ResultViewController.GPAResultLabel = "\(gpa)"
    }
```

Then i got the error saying `Use of unresolved identifier gpa`

what i can do here?

i tried removing `@IBAction func CalculateGpa(sender: AnyObject){` and replacing it with `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {` because sender is anyObject. then i got error

`unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: @Bhavin I did like that and changed `gpa = TotalGiCi/TotalGi` !error `cannot assign 'gpa' in `self``

Comment: use var instead of let in global defination

Comment: @Bhavin Before @IBAction i defined like this globally `let gpa:Float` and inside @IBAction `gpa = TotalGiCi/TotalGi` am i doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define variable globally with `var` because  Variables declared with let must immediately be assigned a value. You cannot simply define a variable with let and no value like you're trying to do on the first line.

If you are modifying value at runtime, which is not what a constant is. Thus, you need a variable, even if its value only changes once.

```
class viewcontroller:UIViewcontroller{

// Define  variable gpa here with its return type...
   var gpa:Float?   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //   relevant code
}

@IBAction func CalculateGpa(sender: AnyObject){
    gpa = TotalGiCi/TotalGi
}

// Data passing code
```

Comment: Got it. and why im getting this error in here `ResultViewController.GPAResultLabel = "\(gpa)"`
 `cannot assign value of type float to a value of type UIlabel`

Comment: ohhh....sorry....you need to give a text property to label....like label.text...and also convert float to string

Answer (score 1):

**Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any function, method, closure, or type context.Global constants and variables are always computed lazily**

Refer the below code.We have declare the variable below like this.

```
 class YourViewControllerName: UIViewController 
 {
   let gpa:Float = TotalGiCi/TotalGi
              //OR
   var gpa:Float = TotalGiCi/TotalGi
   @IBAction func CalculateGpa(sender: AnyObject)
   {
   //all the calculation happen here
   //example
   //Do your Calculation here
   }

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
   {          
      var ResultViewController : ViewControllerResult = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerResult
      ResultViewController.GPAResultLabel = "\(gpa)"
   }
}
```